# Google Earth Engine - Internal server error running analysis on long time series

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am trying to run a code on a 38 years time series of daily rainfall data. It works properly if I subset the dataset (ie: 2000-2018) but I got an error if I run the full time series: 1981-2018: `Internal error`. Sometimes the error message appears in the console, some others it appears in the inspector after clicking a point. In any case i am not able to download the result images because i got an `Internal error`

Any suggestion?

here is the GEE link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3212c4e0e705865c0a63c495e2f70736

here is the code

```
//
// USER SETTINGS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//


var ROI = geometry;


// DATA
var clip = function(img) {return img.clip(ROI);}   
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
                    .filterBounds(ROI)
                    .map(clip);



// Define time range 
var startyear = 1981;
var endyear = 2018;

var startmonth = 7 
var endmonth = 9 

var startday = 1 
var endday = 30  



var precipThresh = 2; 
var DSLength = 15




//
// FUNCTIONS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//

function drySpells(img, list){
  // get previous image
  var prev = ee.Image(ee.List(list).get(-1));
  // find areas gt precipitation threshold (gt==0, lt==1)
  var dry = img.select('precipitation').lt(precipThresh);
  // add previous day counter to today's counter
  var accum = prev.select('counter').add(dry).rename('counter');
  // create a result image for iteration
  // precip < thresh will equall the accumulation of counters
  // otherwise it will equal zero
  var out = img.select('precipitation').addBands(
        img.select('counter').where(dry.eq(1),accum)
      ).uint16();
  return ee.List(list).add(out);
}

// function for calculatin the number of DS by YY
var DS_numb = function(img) {
  var x = img.select('counter').eq(DSLength)
  return img.addBands(x.rename('dryspell')).select('dryspell');
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Set date in ee date format
var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear,startmonth,startday);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear,endmonth,endday).advance(1, 'day');

// create list for years
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear,endyear);

// create list for months
var months = ee.List.sequence(startmonth,endmonth);

//get projection of the CHIRPS dataset
var proj = ee.Image(collection.first()).projection();

// Filter data
var datain = collection.filterDate(startdate, enddate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startmonth,endmonth, 'month'))
  .filterBounds(ROI)
  .map(function(img){
    return img.addBands(ee.Image(0).reproject(proj).uint16().rename('counter'))
  });

// print (datain,'datain')



// create first image for iteration
var first = ee.List([ee.Image(datain.first())]);



// calculate the annual values (NUMB)

// create first image for iteration
var first = ee.List([ee.Image(datain.first())]);

var t1 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(datain.iterate(drySpells,first))

var t2 = t1.map(DS_numb)
// Map.addLayer(ee.Image(t2.first()),{max:10,palette:'#9ecae1,#ffffff,#ffeda0,#feb24c,#f03b20'},'t2')


var YY_TS_N =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
      var w = t2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
            .sum();
    return w.uint16().set('year', y)
}).flatten()).select('dryspell');

print (YY_TS_N, 'YY_TS_N')
// Map.addLayer(ee.Image(YY_TS_N.first()),{max:10,palette:'#9ecae1,#ffffff,#ffeda0,#feb24c,#f03b20'},'Numb Dry Spells')


// do stats
var YY_mean_N = YY_TS_N.select('dryspell').mean().rename('YY_mean');
print (YY_mean_N,'YY_mean_N');
Map.addLayer(YY_mean_N.clip(ROI).select('YY_mean'),{max:90,palette:'#9ecae1,#ffffff,#ffeda0,#feb24c,#f03b20'},'YY_mean_N');

var YY_sum_N = YY_TS_N.select('dryspell').sum().rename('YY_sum');
print (YY_sum_N,'YY_sum_N');
Map.addLayer(YY_sum_N.clip(ROI).select('YY_sum'),{max:90,palette:'#9ecae1,#ffffff,#ffeda0,#feb24c,#f03b20'},'YY_sum_N');

var YY_sd_N = YY_TS_N.select('dryspell').reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev()).rename('YY_sd');
print (YY_sd_N,'YY_sd_N');
Map.addLayer(YY_sd_N.clip(ROI).select('YY_sd'),{min:0, max:30, palette:["lightyellow","MediumOrchid","DarkMagenta"]},'YY_sd_N');


// do return period - (n+1)/x where n=number of years and x=number of events
var events = (YY_TS_N.sum()).clip(ROI)
// print(events,'events')
var y_numb = (endyear-startyear+2)
// print(y_numb,'y_numb')
var YY_rp_N = ee.Image(y_numb).clip(ROI).divide(events).rename('rp')
print(YY_rp_N,'YY_rp_N')
Map.addLayer(YY_rp_N.select('rp'),{min:0, max:100, palette:["lightyellow","MediumOrchid","DarkMagenta"]},'YY_rp_N');




// Calculate trend 


var createTimeBand = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('year').rename("date")); 
};
var YY_TS_N2trend = YY_TS_N.map(createTimeBand);

var YY_senslope_N =YY_TS_N2trend.select('date','dryspell').reduce(ee.Reducer.sensSlope()).clip(ROI)
// Map.addLayer(YY_senslope_N.clip(ROI).select('slope'),{min: [-20], max:[20], palette:["blue","lightyellow","red"]},'YY_senslope_N');

// trend 10 yrs
var YY_senslope_N_10 = YY_senslope_N.multiply(10)
print(YY_senslope_N_10,'YY_senslope_N_10')
Map.addLayer(YY_senslope_N_10.clip(ROI).select('slope'),{min: [-5], max:[5], palette:["blue","lightyellow","red"]},'YY_senslope_10y_N');


////////////////////////////////////////////

var scale = ee.Image(datain.first()).projection().nominalScale().getInfo()

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: YY_sum_N.toInt16(),
  description: 'DSN_sum',
  folder: 'GEE_output',
  scale: scale,
  region: ROI,
});
```